# Kivy Application Package for OSX Failure

Tags: macos, kivy, appkit, py2app, kivy-language

I am having a hell of time packaging my Kivy application. Currently I am trying to get it working on OSX. I have had no luck with the methods in the Kivy documentation or getting help there, so I decided to try py2app. Building it in dev mode works great, but when building it for distribution I get this error in the console. (It seems to be a 10.12 osx issue)

```
Detected missing constraints for <private>.  It cannot be placed 
because there are not enough constraints to fully define the size and 
origin. Add the missing constraints, or set 
translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=YES and constraints will be 
generated for you. If this view is laid out manually on macOS 10.12 and 
later, you may choose to not call [super layout] from your override. 
Set a breakpoint on DETECTED_MISSING_CONSTRAINTS to debug. This error 
will only be logged once.
```

It seems to be an Appkit issue. Is there a way to set the constraint to yes as mentioned in the error through py2app? Or has anyone come across this and found a solution?

Versions used:
Python 3.6
kivy 1.10.0
py2app 0.14

Thanks for the help